# MySQL Merge Column Data

Tags: php, mysql, database, normalization, database-normalization

I downloaded a database table and it wasn't normalised in the slightest. It didn't even have an index!

Anyway, now it looks like this:

```
Id   Word   Type    TypeSet
1    A             
2    A             
3    A      prep.  
4    A            
5    A      prep.  
6    A
```

I'd like `Word` to be have a unique index. For that to happen, the `Type` values have to be merged without keeping duplicates.

I've created a `SET` to store values of `Type` in. I'd like to transfer them all to this set (`TypeSet`) and then delete the `Type` column.

However, to make things worse, some columns store multiple `Type`s!

```
a. & p. p.
a. & pron.
a. & v.
a. & v. t.
```

This can be solved by stripping spaces from the `Type` column and treating `&` as a seperator for these types.

How would I go about transferring `Type` values to the `TypeSet` and merging columns with the same `Word`?

The solution does not have to be fully SQL-only. That's why I've added the PHP tag too.

Comment: Why do you want Word to be unique? What is wrong with the straightforward design for this data? You certainly aren't normalizing. Also, since Id is just a surrogate and you are combining rows, why keep it?

Comment: @philipxy the primary key `Id` is for fast look-ups and inter table relations using foreign keys. The duplicate words are messy. I'll be doing a lot of lookups per second and It'll be much, much cleaner to be able to retrieve a word with its types all in one set.